# How do i set '#cache' attribute value in a renderable array in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to render an image from my custom block. So i have to return an renderable array of an image object from my block.

I have written code like this(snippet), and its working fine.

```
$logo_build = [
       '#theme' => 'image',
       '#width' => $width,
       '#height' => $height,
       '#uri' => $uri,
     ];

     $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
     $renderer->addCacheableDependency($logo_build, $file);

     return [
       'logo' => $logo_build,
     ];
```

but now, how to set '**#cache**' value here ?
 If it return array like below then i can use '**#cache**'. But in the above code how to set '#cache' value ?

```
return array(
     '#cache' => ,
);
```

Comment: $logo_build = [
       '#theme' => 'image',
       '#width' => $width,
       '#height' => $height,
       '#uri' => $uri,
       '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => abc,
        'tags' => xyz,
      ],]; Try something like this

Comment: i have used `'#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.path']]` , but its not working in above way.

Comment: ['contexts' => ['url.path', 'url.query_args'] u arent passing query arguments

Comment: I think `'url.path'` is fine, because its working for me outside the `$logo_build ` array

Comment: What kind of caching are you looking for? When should the cache be invalidated?

Comment: I want to avoid caching the url of the block, and this code was woking for me.

Comment: If it's a block, wouldn't you use getCacheContexts()?